# Re-using a calculated column in the same SELECT query for TimescaleDB continuous aggregates?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am using TimescaleDB 2.6. I am using the real-time aggregation feature of continuous aggregates.

Considering the following query, `SUM(count)` has been calculated three times. And I can not use SELECT subquery within continuous aggregation query as it is one of the limitations of `timescaledb.continuous`.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW table_view
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT 
    TIME_BUCKET('5 minutes', 'timestamp') AS bucket_time, 
    SUM(count) AS _count,
    SUM(cost) AS _cost,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(count)>0 THEN SUM(cost)/SUM(count)
        ELSE 0
        END
    AS avgcost_norm,
FROM source_table
GROUP BY bucket_time
```

I can create a separate view that references `table_view` and use `_count` within its query. But I have concerns about losing the advantages of continuous aggregation as it will be an ordinary view.

Do you have any other suggestion for re-using a calculated column in the same SELECT query for   TimescaleDB continuous aggregates?

Comment: Hello @DrP3x I think Postgres is smart enough to only calculate the value once and then reuse it (effectively). Is there something that suggests otherwise here? I'm wondering if you are having a more general performance issue that has led to you looking that this? An EXPLAIN ANALYZE could be a useful addition to the question?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @greenweeds! I wasn't aware of EXPLAIN ANALYZE. I ran 3 queries 50 times each and calculated the mean and std of execution time for each query. 
1: 20 columns filled with std of the same variable
2: Single column filled with std of the variable, rest is filled with 1s
3: my original query full of condition checks, AVGs, STDs etc.
`m1: 422.13696000000004, std1: 96.71906932123423
m2: 264.81042, std2: 20.044946417010355
m3: 551.8687, std3: 103.26307093115454`
It seems PostgreSQL executes function each time separately even if the argument is the same.

Comment: I decided to use a separate table since the storage is not a big deal and query times are way beyond what I expected. In the end, I gave up using 'timescaledb.continuous' and the problem is solved. :)

Comment: Interesting... thanks for checking that. If you start using EXPLAIN ANALYZE by the way you might also find this community resource (thanks to @depesz :) ) useful for formatting the output https://explain.depesz.com/